# Why won't my ImageBackground view extend to the bottom of the screen in React Native?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

My ImageBackground will only extend as far as it's inner content even though it's parent reaches all the way to the bottom of the screen. How do I get my ImageBackground view to extend fully to the bottom of it's parent view?

```
<View style={styles.container}>
    <View>
        <Text style={styles.closeContainer} onPress={() => this.closeSideBar()}>
            <MBIcon name='ico-24-chevron-left' style={styles.closeIcon} />
            CLOSE
        </Text>
    </View>
    <ScrollView style={styles.contentContainer}>
        <View style={styles.userContainer}>
            <Text style={styles.userName}>{username}</Text>
        </View>
        <ImageBackground source={require('../../assets/drawer-bg.png')} style={styles.imageBackgroundView} imageStyle={styles.imageBackground}>
            <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => Actions.home()}>
                <View>
                    <Text style={styles.links}>Home</Text>
                </View>
            </TouchableOpacity>
            <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => this.performNetworkAction(Actions.orders, {orderStatus: 'notDelivered'})}>
                <View>
                    <Text style={styles.links}>Scheduled Deliveries</Text>
                </View>
            </TouchableOpacity>                                      
        </ImageBackground>
    </ScrollView>
</View>
```

css:

```
container: {
    backgroundColor: '#262626',
    height:'100%',
    width:'100%',
    display: 'flex'
},
contentContainer: {
    height: '100%', 
    flex: 3,
    backgroundColor: '#262626',
    position: 'relative',
    borderColor: 'green',
    borderStyle: 'solid',
    borderWidth: 2
},
imageBackgroundView: {
    width: '100%',
    borderColor: 'yellow',
    borderStyle: 'solid',
    borderWidth: 2,
    position: 'relative',
    flex: 1
},
imageBackground: {
    height: '100%'
},
```

I have outlined my ImageBackground view and it's parent container:

[image]

Comment: Add flex: 1 to imageBackgroundView

Comment: I just tried that but it didnt work.  Is there another way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In scrollView "style" doesn't work instead use "contentContainerStyle"
So this code

```
<ScrollView style={styles.contentContainer}>
```

will become

```
<ScrollView contentContainerStyle={styles.contentContainer}>
```

and add height='100%' in imageBackgroundView

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your understanding of flexbox is a little off. Setting `flex: 1` will cause the view expand to fill space in the direction of its parent's `flexDirection` which by default is `'column'` (vertical). If the parent only has 1 child view with `flex: 1`, the child view will expand to the full space. If 2 child views have `flex: 1` they'll both fill half of the space. The expansion of the child views depends on their parent's `flexDirection` and the flex values of the child views.

Setting `flex: 1` in `imageBackgroundView` should get it to expand to fill the content container.

Comment: Added flex: 1 to the imageBackgroundView style but it did not change anything.  Still does not extend to the fill the space below.  Do I need to add flexDirection to the parent??

Comment: Sorry I missed the content container thing! Glad it's working now. Still, I'd recommend using flexbox instead of `height: '100%'` as flexbox is more… flexible :)